# How to add more storage space for Wine on Linux?

Tags: linux, wine

I use Wine on Linux to install some applications from Windows, but when I finish an install, I see the Wine prompt "Wine hard disk is full".

How can I add more space for Wine?

My Wine version: wine-mono_7.0.0-1 wine_7.0rc5-1
My Linux system: "Garuda KDE Dr460nized"

Comment: The whole Wine + software resides under /home/<user>/.wine. If it says it's full that's because your /home is full. Correct that and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate disk space for Wine, as the other user pointed out. By default, Wine will create a prefix in your `/home` directory and can use any/all space within that partition.

That said, if you have a separate partition or drive that you wish to use for Wine, you can use an environment variable to have Wine create a prefix in the correct place. For example:

```
export WINEPREFIX=/Winebox/winebox-master winecfg
```

On my machine, Wine has a 150GB partition mounted as `/Winebox`. This is completely separate from my `/home` partition.

It's also possible to export the path into your `.bashrc`:

```
export WINEPREFIX=/Winebox/winebox-master
```

Now, anytime Windows `exe` files or Wine commands are executed, it will default to the above Wine prefix path.